# Searching a specific data using VBA inputBox

Tags: vba, excel

Hope someone could give me some tips about this..

I have sheet in excel as my Database, my program is something like you can add a name of a person as many as you want.My Add function performs well, my problem is how can I able to find/search a specific name of that person you want to find using an inputbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PivotTables is what you want, use Slicers to accomplish this. If you can't use Pivots. Look into the `Range.Find` method and the `WorksheetFunction.Match`

Comment: Sorry but the search function is still not written because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This small macro will allow you to enter a name and then tell you where it can be found on the active sheet.

```
Sub FindName()
    Dim v As String
    v = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Name:", Type:=2)
    mesage = ""
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(1, r.Value, v) > 0 Then
            mesage = mesage & r.Address & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
    If mesage = "" Then
        mesage = "Name not found"
    End If
    MsgBox mesage
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why loop through each cell instead of using a Range.Find loop?  Could be started with `Cells.Find(v, , xlValues, xlPart)`

Comment: You are correct!  The .Find() method could be used and may run faster.